# SyntaxError when trying to get style

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web, styles

I'm trying to make a function that fades an object's color to another color in Javascript for a link, but when I use Firebug's JavaScript console, the console gives me a SyntaxError:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error] if (document.getElementById(fadeID).style.color = "#E6E6E6")){
```

The Javascript (I was using alert to test if it was working. If I put it outside the if l:

```
<script>
    function toggleColor(fadeID){
        if (document.getElementById(fadeID).style.color = "#E6E6E6")){
            alert("hi");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<body>
<div id = "content">
    <div id = "header">
        <a onmouseover = "javascript:toggleColor('home')" id = "home" href = "#" title = "Home">Home</a> |
        <a onmouseover = "javascript:toggleColor('music')" id = "music" href = "#" title = "Music">Music</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 if (document.getElementById(fadeID).style.color = "#E6E6E6")){
```

should be

```
 if (document.getElementById(fadeID).style.color == "#E6E6E6"){
```

You are assigning the color with *=*, not comparing. See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4xTGM/)

Comment: And @celloplayer, this is the difference between assigning and comparing in almost every programming language.

Comment: Whoops! How did I miss that?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `)` in your if statement also you are assigning a value instead of comparing it

```
if (document.getElementById(fadeID).style.color == "#E6E6E6"){
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove a clamp and equal sign:

```
if (document.getElementById(fadeID).style.color = "#E6E6E6")){
```

to

```
if (document.getElementById(fadeID).style.color == "#E6E6E6"){ // Here
```